# What are some examples of advantages of working in the C frame or Zero Momentum frame?

Tags: classical-mechanics

So I know that in the C reference frame the momentum of the COM can be taken as 0. But what are the advantages of doing that in problem solving ?

Answer (score -1):

When working in the C frame the energy associated with the center of mass motion, which remains constant during the course of collision and has no effect on the outcome is not present. A simple example is 2 particles moving along the x-axis with same velocity. In the C system this will appear as 2 stationary particles.

Comment: Thanks...I'll be really grateful if you can provide one more example of advantage

Comment: Not mentioned is the fact that the number of coordinates to be solved has been reduced from six in lab coordinates to only three in c-system. Now another example could be an exploding shell. Here you want to know how much of the internal energy of the system is being transferred as kinetic energy of the fragments. The C system here would be the one in which the shell before exploding is taken to be at rest.